# How is a device node created when a piece of hardware is attached to the Computer?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, hotplugging

I want to know how a device node is created when a hardware is connected to the system.

#### Information that I know:

When a piece of hardware is connected to the system, the device name is compared with the driver name, if it matches, then probe is called.

#### Info I wish to know:

At which point is the device node created and who is creating it? (In other words, I want to know where mknod is happening?)

This one thing is bugging my mind from so many months. Please tell me programatically where is this happening.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable edits..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most (but not all!) Linux systems this is handled by [Udev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev).

It is notified of the new hardware through a netlink socket. It then creates the device node, based on its configuration.

Comment: Where is this particular code present inside the kernel code? Please direct me to the respective files. I will look it up myself

Comment: Have you read the link? The Udev code runs entirely in userspace. The netlink messages are of course triggered from the kernel, deeply tied to the kobject system. See lib/kobject_uevent.c for much of the relevant code.

Comment: Yes. I read it now. The linux file name is not written inside it. Thank you for the wonderful answer. I am going through the code. Once i understand it completely i will accept the answer. Thanks once again

Comment: One question. All this happens before calling probe or after calling probe?

Comment: It fits in with kobject so I'd guess when the kobject is created.

Comment: On modern kernels device nodes at `/dev` being managed by the kernel via `devtmpfs`. Kill all instances of `udevd`, insert/remove flash drive and take a look on `/dev` nodes list.